# c# asp.net mvc session start being called multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, global-asax

I have a web site. I am using the session start in global.ascx and while debugging I noticed that it is being called a few times, and jumping from line to line what seems to be different threads. is that normal? must I use the lock statement here?

Comment: It should be called once every new request coming in.

Comment: @Suhas you mean every new session? is there any reason why is won't. I also notice the Application start Method is never hit for some reason.